# brew install gcc48 fails on os10.9

Tags: macos, homebrew, gcc

I tried to install the gcc on brew and it fails. I am tring to find the configure dir...

```
ohad@Macintosh-2:/Volumes/fiverr_dev$ brew install gcc48
Warning: You seem to have osx-gcc-installer installed.
Homebrew doesn't support osx-gcc-installer. It causes many builds to fail and
is an unlicensed distribution of really old Xcode files.
Please run `xcode-select --install` to install the CLT.
Warning: You have an outdated version of /usr/bin/install_name_tool installed.
This will cause binary package installations to fail.
This can happen if you install osx-gcc-installer or RailsInstaller.
To restore it, you must reinstall OS X or restore the binary from
the OS packages.
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-4.8.3/gcc-4.8.3.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc48-4.8.3.tar.bz2
==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.3 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --program-suffix=-4.8 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/
==> make bootstrap
^@^@^@^@^@^@configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `/usr/bin/install_name_tool` with the file linked in [this article](http://www.colinfmurphy.com/how-i-fixed-homebrew-php-complier-error-with-mac-osx-10-9-update/) and then run `xcode-select --install`. Finally open XCode to accept the license.